# Mybatis mapper list return the result repetition

Tags: java, mybatis-sql

I want to use list put into query result,database have two data,but there are four results in the list.,why this repeat  query

```
    <select id="selectList" resultType="map" >
        <foreach collection="list" item="items" separator=" union all ">
            SELECT
            #{items.id,jdbcType=INTEGER} id,
            #{items.name,jdbcType=VARCHAR} name
            FROM category
        </foreach>
    </select>
```

```
    public void selectList() {
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("name", "haha");
        map1.put("id", "1");

        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("name", "update");
        map2.put("id", "2");

        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(map1);
        list.add(map2);

        List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = categoryDao.selectList(list);
        for (Map<String,Object> m : resultList){
            System.out.println(m.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Why there are four here?

Comment: what happened in `categoryDao.selectList(list);`? maybe it added twice. (1) you are adding here and (2) `list`  is changing in `categoryDao.selectList(list);`

Comment: @鹰9am It's unclear what you really want to achieve, but anyway. As you use `union all`, it will execute 2 SELECTs (because the list parameter contains two items) and merge the results. As there are two rows in the `category` table, each SELECT returns 2 rows (with the same column values because the parameters are the same). 2 x 2 = 4. You should enable TRACE level logging so that you can verify the actual SQL, parameters and results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.